# Flutter BLoC: How to add a new event after Navigator.push without wrapping MaterialApp with BlocProvider

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

So I have screen `ExploreScreen` which initiates my BLoC **FilteredRecipesBloc**.
Inside this screen, there is a button that navigates to a new screen `FilterScreen`.
From the `FilterScreen`,  I want to add a new event which affects both screens. The problem now is that I'm getting this error message (**onError Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close**). Is this possible without wrapping MaterialApp with a BlocProvider? I just want local bloc access to two screens.

ExploreScreen:

```dart
class ExploreScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExploreScreenState createState() => _ExploreScreenState();
}

class _ExploreScreenState extends State<ExploreScreen> {
  FilteredRecipesBloc _filteredRecipesBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _filteredRecipesBloc = FilteredRecipesBloc(
        recipeList:
            (BlocProvider.of<RecipesBloc>(context).state as RecipesLoaded)
                .recipeList);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Explore"),
      ),
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => _filteredRecipesBloc,
        child: BlocBuilder<FilteredRecipesBloc, FilteredRecipesState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is FilteredRecipeEmpty) {
            return CategoriesScreen();
          }
          if (state is FilteredRecipesLoading) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _filteredRecipesBloc.add(UpdateRecipesFilter(
                        ingredients: ["Curry"], maxCookTime: 30));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          if (state is FilteredRecipeLoaded) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.recipeList.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                  return ImageRecipeContainer(recipe: state.recipeList[index]);
                });
          }
          return Container();
        }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _navigateToFilterScreen,
        child: Icon(EvaIcons.funnelOutline),
        heroTag: "fafdsf",
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToFilterScreen() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute<FilterScreen>(builder: (context) {
      return BlocProvider.value(
        value: _filteredRecipesBloc,
        child: FilterScreen(_filteredRecipesBloc),
      );
    }));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _filteredRecipesBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Filter Screen:

```dart
class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final FilteredRecipesBloc filteredRecipesBloc;

  FilterScreen(this.filteredRecipesBloc);
  @override
  _FilterScreenState createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {
  Map<String, bool> _selectedCategories = {};
  Map<String, bool> _selectedIngredients = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initIngredientList();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Filter"),),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Category",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ChoiceChip(
                  label: Text("Vegan"),
                selected: _selectedCategories["vegan"] == true,
                onSelected: (isActive){
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedCategories["vegan"] = isActive;
                    });
                },
              ),
              Text("Ingredients"),
              ShowMoreChoiceChips(children: _buildIngredientChoiceChips()),
              RaisedButton(onPressed: _updateFilter),


            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _initIngredientList(){
    List<Recipe> recipeList =
        (BlocProvider.of<RecipesBloc>(context).state as RecipesLoaded).recipeList ?? [];

    for(int i = 0; i < recipeList.length;i++){
      for(int y = 0; y < recipeList[i].ingredientsFlat.length;y++){
        _selectedIngredients[recipeList[i].ingredientsFlat[y].name] = false;
      }
    }
  }

  List<Widget> _buildIngredientChoiceChips(){
    List<Widget> widgetList = [];
    _selectedIngredients.forEach((key, value){
      widgetList.add(ChoiceChip(label: Text(key), selected: value,onSelected: (isActive){
        setState(() {
          _selectedIngredients[key] = isActive;
        });
      },));
    });
    return widgetList;
  }

  void _updateFilter(){
    List<String> ingredients = [];
    _selectedIngredients.forEach((k,v){
      if(v) ingredients.add(k);
    });

    widget.filteredRecipesBloc.add(
        UpdateRecipesFilter(ingredients: ingredients.isNotEmpty ? ingredients : null));
    //BlocProvider.of<FilteredRecipesBloc>(context).add(
      //  UpdateRecipesFilter(ingredients: ingredients.isNotEmpty ? ingredients : null),);
  }
}
```

Comment: What speaks against wrapping MaterialApp with one or more BlocProviders? For your use case it seems to be a valid solution. It helps you to prevent errors that you face right now; for instance, that one screen closed the bloc while others are still using it.

Comment: Just a hint: Your code is a bit redundant. You created an instance of the `FilteredRecipesBloc` in `initState()` and then use `BlocProvider` in your tree. You could remove that `BlocProvider` and just use the `BlocBuilder` with `BlocBuilder(bloc: _filteredRecipesBloc, child...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want StatefulWidget to controll your Bloc. You can instantiate your Bloc in initState method but you don't need to close it via dispose method because it automatically does it for you.

If you have made an instance of the Bloc in initState, you don't want to make another one via BlocProvider. But instead you should use the named constructor `.value`.

Either

```
  FilteredRecipesBloc _filteredRecipesBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _filteredRecipesBloc = FilteredRecipesBloc(
        recipeList:
            (BlocProvider.of<RecipesBloc>(context).state as RecipesLoaded)
                .recipeList);
    super.initState();
  }

  BlocProvider.value(
    value: _filteredRecipesBloc,
    child: ...
  )
```

OR

```
  // Preferable at least for me, because I don't need to bother with the instance of the Bloc.
  BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => FilteredRecipesBloc(
        recipeList:
            (BlocProvider.of<RecipesBloc>(context).state as RecipesLoaded)
                .recipeList),
    child: ...
  )
```

```
class ExploreScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExploreScreenState createState() => _ExploreScreenState();
}

class _ExploreScreenState extends State<ExploreScreen> {
  FilteredRecipesBloc _filteredRecipesBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _filteredRecipesBloc = FilteredRecipesBloc(
        recipeList:
            (BlocProvider.of<RecipesBloc>(context).state as RecipesLoaded)
                .recipeList);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Explore"),
      ),
      body: BlocProvider.value(
        value: _filteredRecipesBloc,
        child: BlocBuilder<FilteredRecipesBloc, FilteredRecipesState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is FilteredRecipeEmpty) {
            return CategoriesScreen();
          }
          if (state is FilteredRecipesLoading) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _filteredRecipesBloc.add(UpdateRecipesFilter(
                        ingredients: ["Curry"], maxCookTime: 30));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          if (state is FilteredRecipeLoaded) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.recipeList.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                  return ImageRecipeContainer(recipe: state.recipeList[index]);
                });
          }
          return Container();
        }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _navigateToFilterScreen,
        child: Icon(EvaIcons.funnelOutline),
        heroTag: "fafdsf",
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToFilterScreen() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute<FilterScreen>(builder: (context) {
      return BlocProvider.value(
        value: _filteredRecipesBloc,
        child: FilterScreen(_filteredRecipesBloc),
      );
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look into this documentation in flutter main documentation

[Resource here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Returning Data',
    home: HomeScreen(),
  ));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Returning Data Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: SelectionButton()),
    );
  }
}

class SelectionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
      },
      child: Text('Pick an option, any option!'),
    );
  }

  // A method that launches the SelectionScreen and awaits the result from
  // Navigator.pop.
  _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
    // Navigator.push returns a Future that completes after calling
    // Navigator.pop on the Selection Screen.
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SelectionScreen()),
    );

    // After the Selection Screen returns a result, hide any previous snackbars
    // and show the new result.
    Scaffold.of(context)
      ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$result")));
  }
}

class SelectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pick an option'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the screen and return "Yep!" as the result.
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'Yep!');
                },
                child: Text('Yep!'),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the screen and return "Nope!" as the result.
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'Nope.');
                },
                child: Text('Nope.'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer to include a code example.